# Inserting Formula with Amperstand and Wildcards

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following formula, inserted through VBA, which looks like this and works

```
"=IF([RowNum] = """", """", COUNTIFS(userSelections[MMM-YY],[Event Date],userSelections[Sev Cat],""1-3""))"
```

But when I add another parameter it stops working

```
"=IF([RowNum] = """", """", COUNTIFS(userSelections[MMM-YY],[Event Date],userSelections[Sev Cat],""1-3"", userSelections[Meds Class], "" * "" & User!$D$13 & "" * ""))"
```

I have also tried escaping the ampersands && but this also didn't work.

Any thoughts on how to get this formula to work? Do I need to escape the cell reference?

Comment: you have so many escaped quotes, I'd use `& Chr(34) &` in VBA code any time you want a `"` character to appear in your final excel-formula for easier readability.

Comment: remove extra spaces around the `*`s. I tested it manually with and without the extra space and it works correctly without the space.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman That and changing the reference format to User!R3C4 solved it. Thanks!